# how to put the last value of a matrix as first value and vice versa

Tags: java, matrix, reverse

Guys i have been trying to put the last value of a matrix as the first and the first value as second but this is my out come

generated matrix es:

```
8, 4, 10, 
4, 6, 9, 
3, 9, 7,
```

upside down matrix:
7, 9, 3, 7, 9, 3, 7, 9, 3,

this is the code:

```
public String segmat(int a[][]) {
    String s = "";
    for (int i =0;i<a.length;i++){
    //for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = a[0].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            s += a[a.length - 1][j] + ", ";
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear: what is "upside down" matrix and how does `7, 9, 3, 7, 9, 3, 7, 9, 3,` represent bringing the last value - first ?

Comment: Your example is not just a swap between first and last item in your matrix.

Comment: According to your code it seems you are trying to repeat last raw of your matrix. You have chosen string type for variable `s` it means you want to just print the matrix and not any calculus. My suggestion to this code is replace `printline` function with return `s`. I even do not know what is your programming language. Please clarify your question and mark some languages as tags!

Comment: well my question was for example if i had a matrix being the first row 8, 4, 10 and the second row 4, 6, 9 and the third row 3, 9, 7 how could i reverse it so i could get 7, 9, 3 on the first row 9, 6, 4 on the second and 10, 4, 8 on the last row I hope this makes the idea a little more clear

Answer (score 0):

This example can be helpful for you

I commented the code so it will be quite easy to understand

```
public class MatrixExample {

    private static int[][] reverse(int[][] matrix){
        int row=matrix.length;
        int column=matrix[0].length; //we have for shure this element, his length is the number of colmn
        int to_return[][] = new int[row][column]; //this is a matrix of the same dimention of the original
        //the indexes that will cicle the row and the column of the new matrix
        int new_row=0; 
        int new_column=0;
        for(int i=row-1;i>-1;i--){ //this will cile the rows from the last to thee first
            for(int j=column-1;j>-1;j--){  //this will cicle the colums from the last to the first
                to_return[new_row][new_column]=matrix[i][j];
                new_column++;
            }
            new_column=0;
            new_row++;
        }
        return to_return;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int matrix[][] = {{ 1, 2, 3},
                        {4, 5, 6},
                        {7, 8, 9},
                        {10,11,12}};

        int[][] new_matrix = reverse(matrix);

        for(int i=0;i<new_matrix.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<new_matrix[0].length;j++){
                System.out.print(new_matrix[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks man it helped me a lot, i was trying to do it with only one variable and at the end i realized i needed more thank you for the help.